# How to save up elixir for upgrade

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've been trying to get enough elixir to upgrade my barracks and unlock the dragon. It seems between training troops for wars and getting raided I can't get enough. Any advice? I can stop training troops to save elixir but I can't control how often I get raided, though after a failed defence raid you get a 12-16 hour shield so that's a good time to stock up.

When someone loses a raid, do they still get to keep the resources they won (even if they get 0 stars)? Does this mean as long as you attack the resources you will get more resources to keep (out of curiosity then what is the point of getting any stars)?

Comment: From my own personal experience and by observing others in my clan, I think unlocking dragons early is not very interesting. They are expensive to create, so if you're already struggling to keep your elixir it's not worth it yet. They are also long to create, so you can't really use them efficiently. Jacob's suggestions is much better, with troops cheap and quick to make in order to attack often

Comment: Dragons are most useful in wars. But I'd also advise you to quickly upgrade them to level 3 coz aerial defences are often really good. So, again it will cost you a lot of elixir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## On defending

My advice for you to save the maximum elixir is to fill your barracks completely before you log out. What this does is consumes elixir to put troops in queue within your barracks thus decreasing the amount of lootable elixir from your elixir storages (you can do the same with your Dark Elixir if you have Dark Barracks).

When you log in next time, just empty your barracks to get the 'stored' elixir back. Before unlocking the dragon, the most expensive unit per slot is the wall breaker. So what I would advise doing would be that you fill your army camps and when they are full, fill up your barracks with wall breakers and for any remaining space, if any, with archers.

<strike>Next is to discourage weaker players from attempting to raid your base and instead go for the win. This is done by placing your Town Hall way outside your main base. Often players will send a few troops to destroy your Town Hall and then walk away with only 1000 gold and elixir, and giving you a 12 hour shield (they know their troops are too weak to break in your main base and take your resources). In contrast, if your Town Hall is hard to reach for weaker players, chances are they won't attack and a stronger player will come by instead and take everything.</strike>
**EDIT: With the 2015 update to shields and loot storage, this is no longer viable.**

My last piece of advice here would be to rearrange your base when needed. You have a few storages and it is not easy to protect everything. Certainly though, you can protect a few more than others at any time. When you need to save elixir, put your elixir storages more in the centre of your base where it would be better protected and move your gold storages further out.

## On attacking

I personally am not a good fan of waiting for my collectors to get the resources I need. I get most of my resources through raiding other bases. My advice now for how to do so:

**Don't be afraid to tap NEXT**

When you are raiding for resources, you really should not care about trophies that much. The best use of trophies at this time would be if you get a nice loot bonus or if you are going for the achievements to get some gems (so that you unlock another builder if you haven't unlocked them all yet). This brings me to the main point: look for bases where the collectors and mines are full. They are not always easy to come by, but a single raid for such bases usually gives you 200k of gold *and* elixir or more and you don't need expensive troops to get them.

Paying a few gold and wait for the perfect opportunities are well worth it. If you find a base with little to no resources, it is best for you to skip and find another to raid.

Send your barbarians and archers to attack those filled up elixir collectors and gold mines. Such bases have usually be abandoned anyway, so you are not doing any harm. Even if you don't win the raid, you will keep the resources.

I will also share this video from a youtuber I follow for this nice video about raiding with examples of full and empty resource buildings and some raid examples: [link](https://youtu.be/vsJ_uoj8xEs)

Comment: All of this is solid advice, and is exactly what I practice myself. +1.

Comment: Nice suggestions about filling up the barracks to 'store' elixir.

Comment: How can you tell before you attack a base if collectors are full of resources?

Comment: @Celeritas You could check [this wiki out](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Flammy's_Strategy_Guides/Attacking:_How_To_Raid_-_Goal:_Get_Resources) maybe? Googling "Clash of clans full vs empty collectors" gives you lots of pictures too.

Comment: @Jerry: I was going to edit out the paragraph about leaving your Town Hall outside your base, but that's a pretty sizable chunk of your answer. Do you want to remove it or otherwise replace it with different information (I can't really think of any to add there).

Comment: @Ellesedil Thanks, I forgot I had an answer here about that ^^

Answer (score 4):

As long as you attack the resources you will get them. What many people do is use army compositions such as Barch (barbarians and archers), GiBarch (giants, barbarians, and archers), or BAM (barbarians, archers, and minions (these armies only take 15-20 minutes to train so you can attack up to 4 times in an hour). If you go to low gold-high silver league and attack bases with high available loot (somewhere above 200k gold and elixir). In about an hour of raiding with these armies (without boosts), I can gain anywhere between 750,000 and 1,500,000 gold and elixir and a few thousand dark elixir.

Another tip is to leave your TH outside so people "snipe" it for trophies. It will give you a 12 hour shield and make it so people can't attack you for a cheap price of just a few trophies.

When you are attacking, don't worry about winning raids and keeping up your trophies. Since you want to be staying in a range anyways, going too high will just cause you to need to drop trophies again.

In response to your final question, the reason behind gaining trophies is to try to get to the top of the leaderboards and get league bonuses. You can also get gems from achievements for trophy pushing. When raiding for loot, there is no reason to worry about leaderboards/league bonuses, just go wherever you can find the most loot.

Comment: Exactly which structures give out the most elixir when attacked? For example I'm guessing elixir drills and elixir storage result in lost elixir but camps and barracks don't  etc ?

Comment: Exactly. Only elixir storages/collectors give elixir, only gold storages/mines give gold, and only dark elixir storages/drills give dark elixir. You can tell how much loot the various storages/collectors have by their graphics. For example, as gold storages fill, coins slowly fill the actual building. The same goes for elixir collectors. If you look at an elixir collector and it appears half full or more, you can raid anywhere between 40k-100k off just that one collector. If you find a base full of these half full collectors/mines you can easily (continued...)

Comment: raid 250k gold and elixir by dropping just a few barbarians and archers on each collector.

Answer (score 1):

Been awhile since I've played some Clash but I'll try my best.

**Raiding**

When someone raids and attacks those resource tanks or the storages they receive a percentage of the values inside. Here is a pretty good list:

[image: Loot Table]
[Table Link and More Important Raid Info!](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids#Loot)

It shows that the higher level you are the less percentage you get. Also if the town hall attacking you is a higher level they receive even less. But they will still get the resources they attack and get, regardless of the star count. There is just a limit to how much they can get.

So in my opinion, because it's one of those games, I would recommend taking advantage of that 8 hour shield and putting the elixir storages in the most protected part of your base. All my opinion, I'm not a pro and probably never will be. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In order to save elixir, you use 18 ballons level 5-6 , 2 dragons and 35 minions to save even more elixir,gold and dark elixir

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends actually. If you are a town hall 7 trying to unlock dragons, I suggest you wait till you are about midway before getting dragons. If you are a town hall 8, I suggest you take your time as in this level, you will be having an abundance of elixir while you run low on the other resources.
I don't suggest that you stop raiding as that is your main source of income at th7+ . You could use a barch army with rage or no spells. If you have lots of space, I suggest having a slight bit more archers than barbarians. Also try dropping or staying in silver 2 as most people there are either dead bases or are bases that are upgrading.
Stars are just like checkpoints, without the respawns. It shows you that you achieved a certain part of the raid. People mostly raid as they want to reach higher leagues for better loot but you could stay in gold 2 or 1. 
People who raid you do keep their resources that were raided even though they lose, but you get a small portion back by the loot cart. Also don't let people snipe your town hall as after the update, resources are stored there too.

Answer (score 0):

look guys use 75% Archers and 25% barbarians. And take 2-3 healing spells and destroy all the resources target for th 7-8 players they have the max lvl resources raid dont worry about elixers and later u can push when all purchase is completed

Comment: why healing spells? I use lightening to take out mortar or x-bow

Answer (score 0):

I managed to stock up 7 million of elixir in 4 days to upgrade my pekka to level 4 by using mostly dark barrack troops. This eliminates any expenditure of elixir (except for the spells) and saves up elixir faster. I used 16 hog, 10 valkyrie, 8 wizard(level 4-7), 4 wall breakers(level 4-6)(Total cost=1340-3740 dark elixir & 34000-50000 elixir)(excluding spell)

The same can be done in case of dark elixir by using mostly elixir based units.
I managed to save 70k dark elixir to upgrade my hound.

Comment: This doesn't answer "When someone loses a raid, do they still get to keep the resources they won (even if they get 0 stars)? Does this mean as long as you attack the resources you will get more resources to keep (out of curiosity then what is the point of getting any stars)?"

Comment: Yes, they get the loot they stole even if they lose.

Comment: Stars add to your star bonus. Other than that it only shows the fraction of trophies u win.  eg. 33 trophies for winning attack, for 1 star 11 trophies (1/3 * 33)

Answer (score -4):

ELIXIR SAVING IS MORE EASY THAN SAYING GOLD!!!!!
THERE IS NEED ONLY FOUR DAYS TO UNLOCK DRAGON....
1.METHOD=USE LOW COST TROOPS ..2 METHOD=LOOK FOR LOOTING(DESTROY RESOURCES)NOT FOR TROPHIES..3 METHOD=MAKE DEFENCE WHICH GIVE MORE IMPORTANCE TO SAVE ELIXIR. these helped me to unlock drag and up him lvl 2 . i am believing it will works... gud luck...and **ENJOY CLASHING...........**